# How can I make German characters from \input file display correctly?

Tags: languages, unicode, input, input-encodings, knitr

I'm working with a `Rnw` file in RStudio and `knitr`.

Everything works correctly so far, but I stumbled upon a problem when I included a chapter to the report that is written in German.

I wrote the German language section in Texmaker and all the German characters are displaying correctly. However when I tried to incorporate it into report using:

`\input{myGermanFile.tex}`

German characters are gone.

The character encoding in RStudio's options is specified as UTF-8.

What can be causing such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

or

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

in your main file.